# Reindexing a series after extracting it from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, series

After extracting a Column from a DataFrame, I end up with a Series. In the Series, I have duplicates of the elements

```
   >> names.head()
      0      Christina Turner
      1      Christina Turner
      2      Christina Turner
      3      Christina Turner
      4    Jackie Hagan-Gross
```

So I follow that with a .drop_duplicates() method

OUTPUT:

```
    0       Christina Turner
    4     Jackie Hagan-Gross
   10          Sherry Spehr
   31           John Bruner
   39      Michael Milleson
```

As you can see, the Index is muddled up. But .reset_index() gives me:

```
  index         KeyContacts
    0      0    Christina Turner
    1      4  Jackie Hagan-Gross
    2     10        Sherry Spehr
    3     31         John Bruner
    4     39    Michael Milleson
```

I need to get rid of the middle row of Indexes. How?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick 
    `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked!